# Mapping columns from two dataframes in R

Tags: r, pattern-matching, string-matching

I have two dataframes with several columns, but for simplicity sake lets say my two dataframes are as such:

```
## Dataframe #1
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("Jake", "Paul", "Luis", "Leon"),
                 salary_new = c(60, 80, 90, 50))

## Dataframe #2
df2 <- data.frame(name = c("Paul Henderson", "John F. Smith", "Leon K.", "Luis Sierra"),
                         salary_old = c(60, 55, 60, 80))
```

I would like to do a sort of mapping between the two name columns where I would replace the names in DF1 with those in DF2 to produce the following results:

```
df3 <- data.frame(name = c("Jake", "Paul Henderson", "Luis Sierra", "Leon K."),
                  salary_new = c(60, 80, 90, 50))
```

What I am having trouble with is that each dataframe has names that don't belong to the other and the ones that do belong have a slight variation to them (include a last name, a middle initial). Is there a way to do a fuzzy matching of sorts to get the desired output and leave the names that aren't in DF2 the same as they appear in DF1?

Comment: You assigned `df2 <- df1 <-`.  Is the df1 the first line of code

Answer (score 1):

We could extract the first word and do a join

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df2 %>%
   mutate(name2 =word(name, 1)) %>%
   left_join(df1, ., by = c("name" = "name2")) %>%
   transmute(name = coalesce( name.y, name), salary_new)
```

-output

```
            name salary_new
1           Jake         60
2 Paul Henderson         80
3    Luis Sierra         90
4        Leon K.         50
```

Answer (score 0):

To do the matching, you can use `fuzzyjoin` with `stringr::str_detect`. Then you have to select which of `name.x` or `name.y` you wanna keep. Here, I keep the name that has the longest string, with `which.max` and `nchar`:

```r
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
fuzzy_right_join(df2, df1, match_fun = stringr::str_detect) %>% 
  mutate(name = apply(across(contains("name")), 1, \(x) x[which.max(nchar(x))])) %>% 
  select(name, salary_new)

#             name salary_new
# 1           Jake         60
# 2 Paul Henderson         80
# 3    Luis Sierra         90
# 4        Leon K.         50
```